# Best jquery plugin for Grid

Tags: jquery, razor, html-table, grid

Working on ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project. Need to show a grid that needs to be inline-editable with pagination (want to get all the data in the grid along with changes). Thanks

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/styling/bootstrap5.html